# Getting 0 results when I use BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-4,CURRENT_DATE) AND DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CURRENT_DATE)

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-format

I am trying to get last 3 months data from the `OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL` CTE that I have created.

`OTO_START_DATE` is in `DATE` format - 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

This query returns 0 results

```
SELECT*
FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL
WHERE OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) 
                         AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

However, when I use this query, I get results

```
SELECT *
FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL
WHERE OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) 
                         AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Check your data and ensure that there are matching dates.

Comment: Presumably because you have data in the last month and not before that? What’s stopping you looking at your data and answering your own question I.e counting records by date and/or by month?

Comment: What if you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL WHERE OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1)` - do you actually *have* any data in that time period in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets get some trival data to check the logic:

```
with OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL(OTO_START_DATE) as (
    select * from values 
    ('2023-08-01'::date),
    ('2023-09-01'::date),
    ('2023-10-01'::date),
    ('2023-11-01'::date),
    ('2023-12-01'::date)   
)
SELECT *
FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL
WHERE OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) 
                         AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

gives:

[image]

Lets workout what could be happening by looking at all the values:

```
with OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL(OTO_START_DATE) as (
    select * from values 
    ('2023-06-01'::date),
    ('2023-07-01'::date),
    ('2023-08-01'::date),
    ('2023-09-01'::date),
    ('2023-10-01'::date),
    ('2023-11-01'::date),
    ('2023-12-01'::date)   
)
SELECT *
    ,CURRENT_DATE
    ,ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) as date_start
    ,ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1) as date_end
    ,OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN date_start and date_end as filter_logic
FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL
--WHERE OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) 
--                         AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

[image]

Well that could be the problem; current_date is the exact "day" and thus a month earlier, which might not be what you want. Perhaps you want to have the start/end of those months at which point you will want to use `DATE_TRUNC('month', current_month)` and `LAST_DATE`

like:

```
with OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL(OTO_START_DATE) as (
    select * from values 
    ('2023-06-01'::date),
    ('2023-07-01'::date),
    ('2023-08-01'::date),
    ('2023-09-01'::date),
    ('2023-10-01'::date),
    ('2023-11-01'::date),
    ('2023-12-01'::date)   
)
SELECT *
    ,CURRENT_DATE
    --,ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4) as date_start
    --,ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1) as date_end
    --,OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN date_start and date_end as filter_logic

    ,ADD_MONTHS(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), -3) as month_start
    ,last_day(CURRENT_DATE, 'month') as month_end
    ,OTO_START_DATE BETWEEN month_start and month_end as filter_logic_2
FROM OTO_HISTORICAL_TRACKING_DETAIL
```

Giving:

[image]